# How can I find the "Device Release Number" for a USB device in .NET?

Tags: .net, windows, usb, wmi

I'm using a ManagementObjectSearcher to find a serial port with a certain USB VID and PID.  I'm also trying to get the "Device Release Number" for the device.  When looking at the properties of the device in Device Manager, this field is visible in the "Hardware Ids" category as follows:

USB\VID_04B4&PID_B71D&REV_0108

(where REV_0108 is the value I'm trying to find programmatically)

I can't seem to find this information in any of the properties of the ManagementObject for the device.  The PNPDeviceID property comes close, but instead of the REV field, there's a long hex string on the end of that value that doesn't seem to have anything to do with what I'm looking for.

Can this information be retrieved using these classes or am I out of luck?

Thanks.